# QlineEdit: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I have a problem. I have QT 5.3.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

For example:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QImage>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QlineEdit>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFile>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QMessageBox>
```

Works well.

The problem is the following line:

```
#include <QlineEdit>
```

Compilator return error: QlineEdit: No such file or directory.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It is spelt [QLineEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html) with an upper-case `L` ! And the English word for French "compilateur" is *compiler*

Comment: Typos are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such class a QlineEdit. However, there is a QLineEdit class.

Note the capital 'L' in Line.

As you've tagged your question with 'Ubuntu' and you're using Linux, it's likely to be case-sensitive, so the capitalisation matters here.